# Django: Where do define var (init or dispatch)

Tags: python, django

I want to add `self.analytics` which I can access from several other methods within the Class. Would you rather define that in dispatch as in the example or in the `__init__`?

```
class Index(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/dashboard/index.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.analytics = EventAnalytics(self.organizers)
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Any linter would ask you to put it inside the constructor, as it should be.

Comment: Constructor means the `__init__`?

Comment: Yup, the `__init__` method

Comment: What is `self.organizers`?